# Meteor i18n - How to have multiple templates, one for each language?

Tags: javascript, meteor

in my i18n.js a map for each language is defined.

```
i18n.map('de_DE',{
    app_name: 'MyApp',
    backButton: 'Zurück',
    main: {
        title:'Some title',
        content: 'Some content'
    },
/*.....*/
```

**How can I load/include the content from an external file?**

Answer (score 0):

create a seperate js file for each language, e.g. 'de.js'

```
export default {
  app_name: 'MyApp',
  backButton: 'Zurück',
   main: {
     title:'Some title',
     content: 'Some content'
   }
};
```

then import it into your i18n.js file

```
import 'de' from './de';
i18n.map('de_DE', de
/*.....*/
```